# keyboard shortcut to switch focus in VSCode on a Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Having a SQL file open in the editor, and `psql` running from the command line using the VSCode terminal, is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle the focus back and forth? I end up doing the <kbd>⌘</kbd> and the <kbd>`</kbd> key to open/close the terminal but it'd be nice just to switch back and forth. Mac user.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question: you can define `workbench.action.terminal.focus` in Keyboard Shortcuts (Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts) and then use that shortcut plus the `CMD+1` to focus back on the editor (or `CMD-2` etc). If someone has something more clever, let me know!